# Drag-on-Drop in Tab Item in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have a tab control with two tab items (TABITEM_A, TABITEM_B). TABITEM_A contains a tree view item that can be drag (in this scenario an tree view item will be drag to TABITEM_B) while TABITEM_B have a listbox that was dragged from TABITEM_A.

I already set the TreeViewDragDropTarget so that I can perform dragging and set the TABITEM_B AllowDrop property to true.

Now, the problem is that when I try to drag an item (from TABITEM_A) to TABITEM_B and drop it (in the highlighted text of TABITEM_B) the Drop event of TABITEM_B is not triggered. Thus, I cannot add the dragged item in the list box of TABITEM_B.

Please help.

Thanks!